# Send Multiple data over network at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, server, client, chat

I want to create a chat application where users can send text messages to each other.
I used TcpClient and NetworkStream to write and read messages, and all worked fine.
but I want to add camera and audio chat, I know how to send a picture and audio, but I want that to be at the same time, you know what I mean?
Like Messanger for example, users can recieve  camera data and audio data at the same time with textmessages. any suggestions?

Comment: Add another stream for the camera and another for the audio

Comment: you mean like that :
Socket mainSocket; //the main socket

NetworkStream ns1 = new NetworkStream(mainSocket); // for text message
NetworkStream ns2 = new NetworkStream(mainSocket); // for camera
NetworkStream ns3 = new NetworkStram(mainSocket); // for audio

like that ?

Comment: Not sure, but I believe you need extra sockets as well.

Comment: OKey I'll give it a try. Thank you @SynerCoder

Comment: You currently have a connection for sending and receiving texts. You just need to duplicate that feat but then instead of sending texts you send pictures. And again but then send audio

Comment: Best would be to do all those 3 things on 3 different threads. So that when the audio or video hangs, you can still send texts

Comment: Okey i'll use 3 background workers for that :) Thanks